# integrating vim/youcomepleteme with anaconda python

Tags: python, vim, anaconda

I am trying to get the Vim plugin YouCompleteme which was working until I installed the Anaconda distro of Python.

Relevant info:

:YcmDebugInfo in Vim returns 
    'E858: Eval Did not return a valid Python object.'

in my vimrc I have:

```
Bundle 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
let g:ycm_auto_trigger = 1
let g:ycm_path_to_python_interpreter = '/Users/briantoomey/anaconda/bin/python'
let g:ycm_filetype_blacklist = {}
```

After poking around other people's vimrc's on github I also tried

```
let g:ycm_path_to_python_interpreter = '/usr/bin/python'
let g:ycm_path_to_python_interpreter = '/usr/bin/python2'
```

The errors being returned in vim are all related to

```
youcompleteme#Enable
```

In bash,

```
$ which python
```

yields

```
$ /Users/briantoomey/anaconda/bin/python
```

and 
    $ python --version

yields

```
$ Python 2.7.6 :: Anaconda 1.9.0 (x86_64)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think the trouble is that the Python which your build of vim was linked against at build time might be different than the version in your Anaconda install.  It looks like you're on a Mac.  If you're using MacVim, you can do:

    "otool -L /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim"

And look to see which version of Python it's linked to.  This is just a guess, though, since I don't know how the YCM extension works; it might be completely independent of vim's built-in Python support. You can also check out: http://bit.ly/1mGBQZ6

Comment: If you can reproduce that this is an issue related to Anaconda, not your particular system setup, why don't you open an issue in YouCompleteMe's issue tracker?!

Comment: I had similar pain getting this to work (though a different error), python sys.executable mismatched sys.version (when called with `:python`), one to the system one to anaconda. I've got this working with them both pointing to the system (which is not what I want!). Did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the same situation as @Andy_Haden and came across this comment on github issue 8 (https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/8) by chrischoy:

"""
For anaconda users,

Just temporarily change the python-config file in /path/to/anaconda/bin/python-config to python-config.tmp while compiling YCM and rename back to normal. It will do the trick.
"""

Answer (score 1):

OS: Redhat 7

Error: YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python (2.7.1+ or 3.4+) support

Required conda environment deactivation.

```
rm -rf ~/.vim ~/vim #start fresh if needed
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
git clone https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
cd vim/src
```

LEAVE CONDA ENVIRONMENT `conda deactivate` (multiple times if need to exit base)

Note: "full path to" needs to be changed to full path to conda install.  Test path is correct with `ls` before configuring.

```
./configure --disable-nls --enable-cscope --enable-gui=no --enable-multibyte --enable-pythoninterp --enable-rubyinterp --with-features=huge --with-python-config-dir=<full path to>/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu --with-tlib=ncurses --without-x
make
sudo make install
```

Activate back into conda environment. `conda activate <my env>`

Place into .vimrc (included NERDTree and flake8) :

```
set nocompatible              " required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

" add all your plugins here (note older versions of Vundle
" used Bundle instead of Plugin)

" ...

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

" Enable folding
set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevel=99

" Enable folding with the spacebar
nnoremap <space> za

Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'

Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'

set encoding=utf-8

Bundle 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'

let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion=1
map <leader>g  :YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration<CR>

Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'

Plugin 'nvie/vim-flake8'

let python_highlight_all=1
syntax on

Plugin 'jnurmine/Zenburn'
Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'

Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'

Plugin 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'

let NERDTreeIgnore=['\.pyc$', '\~$'] "ignore files in NERDTree
```

Install:

```
vim #enter vim
:PluginInstall #at command prompt

cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe 
python3 ./install.py #youcompleteme requires an installation step
```

Test installation by opening a python file with vim

Comment: When installing YouCompleteMe instructions worked for and tested on macOS 10.13 and 10.14.  Required `cmake` in conda environment, and required python being installed or updated using `conda install python -c conda-forge`.

Answer (score 0):

I use anaconda but use [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/) to provide my python binaries. So far I have been able to use it with YouCompleteMe without any problems. To use it you should just need to do the following, which is also listed on their website.

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge 
conda install python
```

Then build YouCompleteMe normally and it should just work. I've done this successfully with Python 3.6 and 3.7.